# How to detemine file extension on php upload?

Tags: php, file-upload

I've read something about `MIME` and `finfo()` but I didn't understand!

Also I tried these:

```
if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["type"] == "text/docx"/*or == document/docx*/)
    echo "1";
```

It is obviously that it won't work.
When I `echo $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'];` then I saw this for a word document(My server is Linux):

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

So must I use: ?

```
    if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
```

What is an easy and reliable way to find file extension(Not only Images)?
(I mean using some variables which are not filled on client side)

Comment: As you said, detecting the (MIME) type yourself is the way to go. What about it don't understand you?

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question here

Comment: This is the output of the example of php.net
text/html
image/gif
application/vnd.ms-excel
I want something like this : ".docx" ".exe" ".html" NOT text/html

Comment: should I use search function and find last "."?

Comment: No you should not. That may give you the extension, but it does not necessarily tell you what file you're really working with. Filenames (and extensions) are completely arbitrary and a user can simply fake the extension if he wants to give you a wrong file type. The MIME type (text/html etc.) is what you typically want to identify what a file is. You can easily translate this into a file extension later when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using php 5.3, you can get *true* mime-type:

```
$finfo = finfo_open();
$file = $_FILES["uploadedFile"];
finfo_file($finfo, $file, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
$file = $_FILES['uploadedFile'['name'];
$pathparts = pathinfo($file);
$ext = $pathparts['extension'];
```

This will give you the actual file extension to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to determine the file type is by examining the first few bytes of a file – referred to as “magic bytes”. Magic bytes are essentially signatures that vary in length between 2 to 40 bytes in the file headers, or at the end of a file.

your best bet  is PECL extension called [Fileinfo](http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo).

As of **PHP 5.3**, Fileinfo is shipped with the main distribution and is enabled by default

```
// in PHP 4 :
$fhandle = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
$mime_type = finfo_file($fhandle,$file); // e.g. gives for example "image/jpeg" for a jpeg file

// in PHP 5 you can do :

$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);  // object oriented approach!
$mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($file));
```